# jquery to check which value in an array of checkboxes is checked

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an array list of two things on a form with a disabled button. I need to use jQuery to check which value is checked, and if a certain one is checked re-enable the submit button.

The model:

```html
private List<String> billTypeOptions;
```

The controller:

```html
List<String> billTypeList = new ArrayList<String>();
billTypeList.add("Direct Bill");
billTypeList.add("Agency Bill");
model.addAttribute("billTypeList", billTypeList);
ams360Policy.setBillTypeOptions(billTypeList);
```

The HTML:

```html
<td id="billTypeCell">
  <div th:each="billType : ${billTypeList}">
      <input class="bto" type="checkbox" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].billTypeOptions}" th:value="${billType}" value="off"/>
      <label th:text="${billType}" id="billTypeLabel"></label>
  </div>
</td>
```

I've tried this:

```html
if($('.bto').is(":checked"){
   $('#send').attr("disabled",false);
 }
```

But it seems to not work because the page needs to reload to register the checking. Any idea how to get this to work without reloading the page?

I've also tried

```js
if ($('.bto').val() == 'Direct Bill")
```

```js
if ($('.bto').value == 'Direct Bill")
```

Comment: You're repeating the bto id in the loop, and the billTypeLabel id

Comment: ^ To fix the problem, change them to `class` attributes, and amend the selectors in your JS

Comment: @Taplar, Oh sorry, yes I caught that and it still doesn't work. I will adjust the code.

Comment: Also be aware that `.val()` isn't going to loop over the elements and find the one that matches, or return an array.  It's only going to return the value for the first element in the result stack.

Comment: So I've realized the issue I'm having with the above suggestions is that the page needs to be refreshed to be able to process the checking of the checkbox. Any idea how to fix this so the page doesn't need to be refreshed but can process the click function? Maybe instead of doing is("checked") I should do .click()?